# How to return the translated string in a custom translation shortcode in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a translation plugin ([Loco Translate](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)), and I want to translate my page using `<?php _e('text', 'domain'); ?>` in my page editor in the wordpress administration. Is it possible ?
I tried shortcodes but the result is commented ... Thanks !

**EDIT :**

My shortcode function :

```
function translation_shortcode($atts) {

     $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'name' => '',
    ), $atts );

    return "<?php echo __('" . $a['name'] . "', 'pulsdesign'); ?>";
}

add_shortcode( 'translation', 'translation_shortcode' );
```

In the page editor :

```
[translation name="Softwares and sensors for remote and real time physiological monitoring"]
```

The result :

```
<!--?php echo __('Softwares and sensors for remote and real time physiological monitoring', 'pulsdesign'); ?-->
```

Comment: Show us *how* you tried short codes. https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: See the edited post

Comment: try to return the translated content as: return __($a['name'], 'pulsdesign');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be `return "<?php echo __('" . $a['name'] . "', 'pulsdesign'); ?>";`

This will return the *string* `<?php ...`, which will end up in the browser as a whole. And browsers don't know what to do with php code, they can't execute it.

Instead you should return the result of the translation, as Marcel Kohls commented:

`return __($a['name'] 'pulsdesign');`